# java spring javax.inject.provider throwing class cast exception

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Im currently creating a spring bean with the following javax inject provider annotation:

```
@Autowired
Provider<Table> provider;
```

in one of the init methods i call :

```
Table table = provider.get();
```

this throws : java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy127

The table is configured as a

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Table extends Furniture<
        Square,
        Round>  {

   ...............
   ...............

}
```

With the parent class being abstract:

```
public abstract class Furniture<
    E extends Legs,
    M extends Corners>  {

    .............
    .............

}
```

Anyone got any ideas why i cannot get an instance to be created on init?

I know spring has method injection using the lookup method, but i dont really want to use the XML.

Comment: maybe i need to use @inject?... but @autowire and inject should be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the bean returned by the provider gets proxied. Try to extract an interface that the `Table` class can implement, and use a `Provider<TableInterface>` instead. Then you can get an instance like:

```
TableInterface table = provider.get();
```

Which would still return a `Proxy`, but you wouldn't get the `ClassCastException` on this assignment, because the proxy implements the `TableInterface` interface.

Another possibility is to enable class proxying with CGLIB, in which case you don't need to extract an interface.

Comment: Yes my furniture class already has an interface, but that interface is  shared among different classes.. in this is case i wanted an instance of table.. not chair... is it possible to give it an interface and then specify which class instance i want created and wrapped by the proxy?

Comment: would this work <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>?

Comment: Yes, it should. You need to understand the difference between the two [proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying). The more lightweight JDK proxy is only able to implement interfaces, but cannot extend concrete classes. So a JDK proxy can never be a `Table`, it can only wrap it, implement the interfaces that `Table` implements, and delegate the methods defined in those interfaces. By `proxy-target-class="true"` you enable the use of CGLIB proxies which are more powerful, and can extend concrete classes.